# Failed Windows update restored old HD snapshot?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Last night, apparently a Windows update failed (updating Windows version from 1703 to 1903) and suddenly my lock screen was back to password instead of PIN. I understand that this sometimes happens with some recent KBs but what's even stranger is that it seems like the rest of my C: also reverted back to some old state/snapshot.

I had a couple recent virtual machines in C:\VMWare (as of late 2019) and they're completely gone. The folder is still there with old files in it. Some recent programs are missing from my Program Files folder, too.

My other HDs (I have 4 others) aren't affected at all. Only my C: (main Windows partition).

I'm trying to understand what happened. The profile is something I have backed up but I have no recent backups of those VMs and tools like Restoration don't find anything to recover.

That's REALLY bad... That's about 500 gigabytes of data just completely wiped out without any interaction or confirmation from me, all because an update failed?

Can anyone shed light on the technical details of what likely happened here?

It seems like the hard drive has basically gone back 2.5 years. The latest file timestamps on everything are from 2017. Rebooting in safe mode didn't work and the files were truly gone. HDD space was free (1 TB was about 90% full and is now 30% full).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what happened here because it literally just happened again this morning but this time it restored C: back to the 2/28 state (the day before I posted the above question), which prompted an obvious what-the- moment.

After a Windows update this morning, it rebooted into a black screen that was unresponsive to anything (including the Ctrl+Alt+Delete workaround from last year), and then I did a hard reboot and I was suddenly back to my C: state in 2/28, which I thought had been deleted, per my post above.

It turns out that the problem (sort of) was that I had my old C: hard drive connected (SATA) from a previous PC upgrade, and it was mapped to drive letter S: with the "C" volume label (I probably should have called it "Old C", though). I had only had this thing connected so I could migrate some old files over a couple years ago and I never disconnected it.

Apparently the Windows Update was SWAPPING the contents of these drives (at least the majority of the contents). So in my above post, when I couldn't figure out how it had magically restored about 300 gigs of old data, it was because it had actually pulled that from my old hard drive, and then had moved my true profile back to that old drive.

So this morning, it swapped it again and my profile from yesterday was now in the old hard drive, and my 2/28 profile was in my current hard drive.

I still have no idea what the logic is behind Microsoft doing this, or how it auto-magically decided, "Hey, here's a completely different hard drive that ALSO has a Users and Windows folder, I might as well treat it completely differently from all the other data drives."

...but the good news is that today I now have access to a lot of data that I thought I had lost permanently. And now that I know the data was moved to the old hard drive, I know where to look if this happens again. It's still pretty inconvenient since the profile / registry data itself is still from 2/28, so I have to re-install any applications from the past 2 months, but that's acceptable for now.